# glDrawArrays gives vertical lines when using GL_POINTS

Tags: windows, opengl, gldrawarrays

I'm drawing a points using `glDrawArrays` with `GL_POINTS`. 
On my `Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family` everything is working fine.
But on `ATI Radeon Mobility 5730` vertical lines appear randomly when resizing the window.

Here is the code that renders the picture:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(color_p_v,GL_FLOAT,offset,color_array);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,N);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

I have omitted the array initialization here.

I have checked with `gDEBugger` that lines are rendered into back buffer after the `glDrawArrays` function is executed.

I saw similar questions here but people are having similar problems when rendering a texture. My case is a bit simpler.

Also there are advice not to use `GL_POINTS` but this sounds strange to me.

I want to understand what is going on under the hood.

IMHO there is band implementation in particular driver but what is really going on?

Comment: do the lines remain after a clearbuffer and rerender?

Comment: It's certainly not wrong to use `GL_POINTS`; with point sprites they are an effective way of doing various funny operations.

Comment: Enable Double buffering.

You could stop the render while is resizing.

Comment: You cannot draw the window while it is resizing anyway. Windows stops running the normal message pump while this is happening. One trick, however, is to run a timer at ***0 ms*** intervals when resizing begins and stop the timer when it finishes. Windows will continue to send timer events while resizing a window.

Comment: The lines appear at the certain width of the window. When they appear i'm covering the window with other windows(causing the WM_PAINT message and window rerender). The lines still there.

Comment: I'm using PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER to enable double buffering.

Comment: I'm rerendering window on resize but in that case why do lines remain when the window is not resized after resizing. Repaint doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i have found the problem.
When specifying coordinates as in float like (5,6) for instance on ATI i get vertical lines.
When specifying (5+0.5f,6+0.5f) everything is fine on all systems.
This related how driver interprets the coordinates and pixel position.
Integer coordinates values are lying between pixels not in the center of them.

I would like to read more about that issue but failed to find any good article on that.

Comment: This is not up to the driver. It is exactly specified (unless you tell OpenGL to use a different convention). Read http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/fragment_coord_conventions.txt